# Neptune time of perihelion/ephemeris dates

Tags: ephemeris, neptune

Is there a data online for the time of perihelion of Neptune between 2000AD and 3000AD? I need values in Julian Date (JD).

I tried using HORIZONS Web interface, but it won't generate ephemeris for Neptune after a certain calendar date.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Horizons only goes up to 2050 for Neptune. https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/eph_spans.cgi?id=A But try the Neptune barycenter, which goes upto 9999.

Comment: Do you have a link? I don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I was busy figuring it out myself. :) You need to use planet command code `8` not `899`. It seems to work ok. I just tested it for 4000 AD. I got slightly confused because the JD of Tp changes, but I guess that's because the orbit is precessing. I don't have a link that explains what to do, apart from the Horizons docs. But I could give you a link that generates the ephemeris. What time step do you want?

Comment: [This link](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons_batch.cgi?COMMAND=%278%27&CENTER=%27500%400%27&MAKE_EPHEM=%27YES%27&TABLE_TYPE=%27ELEMENTS%27&START_TIME=%272000-jan-01%27&STOP_TIME=%273000-jan-01%27&STEP_SIZE=%2710+Y%27&OUT_UNITS=%27AU-D%27&REF_PLANE=%27ECLIPTIC%27&REF_SYSTEM=%27J2000%27&TP_TYPE=%27ABSOLUTE%27&ELEM_LABELS=%27YES%27&CSV_FORMAT=%27NO%27&OBJ_DATA=%27NO%27&batch=1) gives you the Neptune barycenter orbital elements, including Tp, the time of perihelion passage, from 2000 AD to 3000 AD, with a step size of 10 years.